# Retrieving data from firebase IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database. Below is the code i use do this. I have my listener in my viewDidLoad function, when i first open the application the data from my database isnt being retrieved, it is only retrieved when i leave that view controller and then return to it. What is causing this Problem?

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("viewdidload")
        FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "projects").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            // 2
            print("firbase")
            var newItems: [projectObject] = []

        // 3
        for item in snapshot.children {
            // 4
            print("for")
            let project = projectObject(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)

            newItems.append(project)
        }

        // 5
        self.projects = newItems
        self.projectsTableView?.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: what is your problem if any error then update it

Comment: reload your table in main queue  `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.projectsTableView?.reloadData() }`

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger? If you set a breakpoint on the `print("firebase")` line, do you ever get there?

Comment: @Rajat that didn't work

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen it doesn't trigger when the view is first loaded, the print("firebase") is  only printed when I leave the view and comeback to it (ie go to another view controller and then return to it)